# Why is Rspec not keeping up with the app it's testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pry

I have:

```
class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :delayed_create_matching_surveys
end

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_matching_results, :touch_review
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :update_inputs
  def update_inputs
    if input_id.present?
      @input = Input.find(input_id)
      if survey.reload.results.sort_by{|r| r.points}.last.selected
        competitor.inputs << @input unless competitor.inputs.include?(@input)
      else
        competitor.inputs.delete(@input) if competitor.inputs.include?(@input)
      end
    end
    binding.pry_remote ## << which exists purely to slow down the app
  end
end
```

I have configured Sidekiq to execute all delayed methods immediately in the test environment. I have also tried removing the `delay_` and have confirmed this does not solve the problem.

With this code, the following spec passes:

```
describe "update_inputs" do

  before :each do
    @product = create(:product)
    @question = create(:question, :product => @product)
    @review = create(:review, :product => @product)
    @client = @review.competitors.first
    @competitor = create(:competitor, :review => @review)
    @category = create(:category)
    @input1 = create(:input)
    @input2 = create(:input)
    @competitor.categories << @category
    @input1.categories << @category
    @input2.categories << @category
  end
  it "assigns one input to a competitor when one is selected" do
    @survey = @competitor.reload.surveys.select{|s| s.input_id == @input1.id}.first
    @survey.results.select{|r| r.name.include?("sells this product")}.first.update_attributes :selected => true
    @competitor.inputs.should == [@input1]
  end
end
```

All I have to do is type `pry-remote` and then `exit` when Rspec gets to `binding.pry_remote`.

It seems all it's doing is slowing my app down long enough for Rspec to catch up.

But without `binding.pry_remote`, the spec fails. Without it, `@competitor.inputs` is `[]`, as is `@competitor.reload.inputs` and `@competitor.inputs(true)` and `@competitor.reload.inputs(true)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When is `update_inputs` called in your example? There's no obvious place in your test where that method is ever invoked. Without knowing when it is called I don't see how anyone can debug a timing or sequencing issue.

Comment: sorry i will update now to show that info -- `after_update :update_inputs`